# Move data from parent table (A) and its child table (B) to parent table (C) and its child table (D) - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I am having trouble writing query or procedure. My requirement is I want to move data from table A and its child table B to new parent table (C) and its child table (D) with same structure.

Primary key column in table A is inserted into one of the column in table B for reference. The challege I have is when I move from Parent table A to new parent table C , new primary key will generated. I want to insert that newly generated key into table D with corresponding rows when I move the data from child table B to new child table D.

It might be simply procedure or query to someone. But i am not able to figureout . Need some help!

Comment: Table A, B , C and D are already create have some data in all the tables. I want to move bunch of rows (only 10 ids I have) from A to C and its corresponding rows from B to D

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a table A:

CREATE TABLE a (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  some_data varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=XXX;

And table C:

CREATE TABLE c (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  some_data varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=YYY;

Write your auto_increment value on table c and remove it from your c.id:

ALTER TABLE c CHANGE id id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL;

Create a temporary table eg. tmp_copy_a_c with the same auto_increment vaule:
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_copy_a_c (
  id_c int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_a int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  some_data varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (id_c),
  INDEX (id_a)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=YYY;

Then copy all data from A to the temp table:

INSERT INTO tmp_copy_a_c(id_a, some_data) SELECT id, some_data FROM a WHERE "some conditions on table a";

Copy from tmp_copy_a_c to table c:
INSERT INTO c(id, some_data) SELECT id_c, some_data FROM tmp_copy_a_c;

Copy data from table B to table D (assuming id_d is another autoincrement):
INSERT INTO d(id_c, some_child_data) 
SELECT tmp.id_c, b.some_child_data 
FROM tmp_copy_a_c tmp
JOIN b
  ON tmp.id_a = b.id_a;

Recreate the auto_increment on table C like this:

ALTER TABLE c CHANGE id id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

NOTE: This solution supposes that tables are not growing/being changed by other processes while running this script.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't mention this in my question. Table A, B , C and D are already create have some data in all the tables. Yes you are correct "auto_increment value on primary key" on table A as well table C. I want to move bunch of rows (only 10 ids I have) from A to C. And there was no foreign key relations created in this table and I can't chnage it !

Comment: Ok, so let's say you have IDs 1-100 in table A and IDs 1-150 in table C. Now you want to copy all rows from A to C with new IDs 151-250 and the same IDs in referencing columns of table D?

Comment: Yes you are correct . one small change from table A IDs 1- 100 , I don't want to move all the rows with ID 1 - 100. I have some list of IDs from table A. I want to move only those Ids. I was researching on this and looks like I have to use cursor to write program to do this.

Comment: Changed the answer according to your additional info. Hope it helps!

Comment: The challenge I have is I can't alter the table . I have to think other solution. Thanks for your help though !